# Fatal error on prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Updated...

I am writing prepared statements and I´m getting this error message:

**Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\inlogg_och_lagar\core.inc.php on line 34**

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\inlogg_och_lagar\core.inc.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\inlogg_och_lagar\core.inc.php(34): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\inlogg_och_lagar\index.php(23): getuserrow('username') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\inlogg_och_lagar\core.inc.php on line 34**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
It´s a simple login script.

Here is the loginform.inc.php

```
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'] ;    
        $password = $_POST['password'] ;

        $password_hash = md5 ($password);   


        if ($username && $password)
        {     
          $query  ="SELECT * FROM USERDATA where `username` = :username AND `password` = :password";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
   ':username' => $_POST['username'],
   ':password' => $password_hash
));

$row = (bool) $stmt->fetch();
            if (!$rows)
            {   
                  echo '<p class="warning">Fel användarnamn/lösenords kombination.</p>';
            } else {    
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;
            }
        } else {    
              echo '<p class="warning">Du måste fylla i ett användarnamn och lösenord</p>';
            }
    }
    ?>

        <!--- LOGIN FORM --->
        <div id="form-column">
            <p>You need to be loggedin.</p>
            <p>Fill out username and password.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST"> 
                Användarnamn: <input type="text" name="username"> 
                Lösenord: <input type="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here is the core.inc.php

```
    <?php 
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])&&!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $http_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }


    function loggedin () {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            return true;
        }   else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function getuserrow ($row) {
    $sql  ="SELECT * FROM USERDATA where id = ?".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}

    ?>
```

And here is the connect.inc.php

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);

?>
```

Comment: `$dbh` or `$pdo`. Chose one.

Comment: your PDO object is referenced to `$pdo` why you use `$dbh`

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I have now tried to change and go with pdo but then get another error message. I have made updates to the code and question above, if you have any idea what is wrong please let me know. @hjpotter92

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I have now tried to change and go with pdo but then get another error message. I have made updates to the code and question above, if you have any idea what is wrong please let me know. @Shushant

Answer (score 1):

Your PDO object is defined as `$pdo`, but later referenced as `$dbh`:

- From `connect.inc.php`:

  ```
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
  ```
- From `loginform.inc.php`:

  ```
  global $dbh;
  // ...
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  ```

Furthermore, `loginform.inc.php` does not appear to include `connect.inc.php`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! Ok I see what you mean, can I just change $dbh to $pdo on every place $dbh is written? Both the connect.inc.php file and lohinform.inc.php are included on the pages that you can log in. So on index.php they are both included, it worked fine before I started fizzling with prepared statement but with prepared statement do I need to included the connect.in.php in loginform.inc.php as well? @eggyal

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question with the suggested changes in the code but I get another error message... Can you tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing second parameter at `$stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']))`
it should be

```
$sql  ="SELECT * FROM USERDATA where username = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password'])));//<== here
```

Comment: Ah yes you were right! I have tried to change this but I still can´t get the script to log in. It just says wrong password/username combination.                                    `if (!$row)
        {   
              echo '<p class="warning">Wrong password/username combination.</p>';
        } else {    
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }`

Comment: i have updated my post and i think you are not comfortable to use PDO consider using http://fluentpdo.com/

Comment: Ok, now I´m back to this Error message: **Notice: Array to string conversion in ...**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...**

Comment: old error is `$pdo` is not an instance of object `PDO` try to solve it your self

Answer (score 1):

Replace this,

```
global $pdo;  // <- You don't need this one
$sql  ="SELECT * FROM USERDATA where username = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

with

```
$query  ="SELECT * FROM USERDATA where `username` = :username AND `password` = :password";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
   ':username' => $_POST['username'],
   ':password' => $password_hash
));

$row = (bool) $stmt->fetch();
```

In order to avoid situations like this one, you'd better stick with named placeholders instead of unnamed ones (like `?`).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing! I have tried this but the script still does not log in. It just says wrong password/username combination. Any idea what is wrong? It seems that there is soemthing wrong with this part: `if (!$row)
  {   
     echo '<p class="warning">Wrong password/username combination.</p>';
  } else {    
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row;
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit;
  }`

Comment: Hi, just tried this as well and the error messages just keep coming. I have updated the question with error message and the code in core.inc.php. I think the function getuserrow is something wrong. I´m sorry, I´m a beginner at this and just can´t figure out what is wrong:/

Comment: Nevermind, I´ll get my teacher to explain this to me as I´m really lost... I´m not checking this as solved as it´s not solved but I´ll upvote your answer!:) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since you're writing a login form, you should take it as a "task". Then you're should break down the task into small ones. Then you should solve those small tasks. What the hell does it mean? Well, as you might know a log-in form consists of `Input Validation`, `Record Validation` (Input and Record validators aren't the same), Storage (Either session or cookies for "Remember me" feature), Storage validation (Checks whether a user is already logged-in). So, you have **actually** 4 problems to solve. Your problem is that you're mixing **everything**, thus your code is getting harder to read.

Comment: The very first thing you might want to do is to learn basic OOP. Since you can use buil-in `PDO` class, that won't be too hard for you. Oh come on, it will take you about 2-3 hours!

Comment: And yes, LOL, your problem is that you're cheking for `$rows` (A variables that does not exist!!). If you re-read that code, you'd catch this, it should be not `if (!$rows)`, but `if (!$row)`

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply, I think I´m starting to get a grip on PDO now! But it is pretty comfusing to first learn one way (mysql) and right when starting to get a grip you´re suppose to do things another way... Yeah I noticed the $row misspelling in my post...